# find proportions between two length

Tags: geometry

let us consider following problem :

A tower casts a shadow of $6$ meters at a certain time of the day. If at exactly the same time, a man stands at the top of the tower, the length of the shadow increases by $2$ meters. What is the height of the man if the tower is $5$ meters high?

we have following diagram

[image]

i wanted to  determine if these two triangle are similar,but solution  of this problem says that

The basic concept is that when the man stands on the top of the tower, the length of the shadow increases proportionately to total height of the tower and the man,

if there is not  similar between triangles according angles,how can i assume this?please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangles *are* similar, but the solution you quote from prefers (for some reason) to view the problem algebraically rather than geometrically.

The fundamental observation is that because the sun is very far away -- we can assume it is "at infinity", certainly for the purpose of measuring shadows -- the two diagonal lines in your diagram are *parallel*. In particular they have the same slope, so for some $m$ we have

$$6m=5 \qquad\text{and}\qquad (2+6)m=5+x$$

Then $m$ is the proportionality constant your model solution speaks of. Solve the left equation for $m$ and insert into the right one to get an equation for $x$.

Comment: By the way, we also assume that the center of Earth is infinitely far away :)

Comment: @Hagen: No just that the ground is flat and perpendicular to the tower in its immediate vicinity. :-)

Comment: does it means that parallel lines when they cut  two intersected lines ,do they cut proportional length or?

Comment: @dato: Yes -- because the lines are parallel, all of the angles in the two triangles are the same, so they are similar.

Comment: could you give me link of such   statements?

Comment: is it this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparallel_(mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

The Sun is a very very large object (as compared to the Earth) that emits lights.  Thus, all light rays from the Sun are considered as parallel (rather than radiating). That is why your figure consists of two similar triangles.

Besides, the fastest way to compute x is :-

x / 5 = 2 / 6 giving x = 5 / 3.